# Why I am unable to cast concrete generic to paremeter with interface?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, asp.net-mvc-5, covariance, contravariance

I have read many questions related to this and perhaps this is a duplicate but I still can't understand this concept. From what I read this is related to [covariance and contravariance](http://tomasp.net/blog/variance-explained.aspx/).

I have these interfaces and classes:

```
public interface IBaseEntity
public interface IRepository<T> where T : IBaseEntity

public interface ITravelRequest : IBaseEntity
public interface IUser : IBaseEntity

public class TravelRequest : ITravelRequest
public class User:  IUser
```

I have this controller:

```
public TravelRequestsController(IRepository<ITravelRequest> repository, IRepository<IUser> userRepositor)
```

I am trying to inject the repositories by creating them like this:

```
var travelRequestRepository = new Repository<TravelRequest>(context);
var userRepository = new Repository<User>(context);

var controller = new TravelRequestsController(travelRequestRepository, userRepository);
```

but I get this error:

```
Error   4   Argument 1: cannot convert from
DAL.Repository<Elite.Models.TravelRequest.TravelRequest>' to
DAL.IRepository<Elite.Models.TravelRequest.ITravelRequest>'
```

how can I make this work?

UPDATE - Full body of IRepository

```
 public interface IRepository<T> where T : IBaseEntity
    {
        IEnumerable<T> AsQueryable();

        IList<T> GetAll();
        IList<T> Find(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate);
        T Single(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate);
        T SingleOrDefault(Expression<Func<T,bool>> predicate);
        T First(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate);
        T GetById(int id);

        T Create();
        void Add(T entity);
        void Delete(T entity);
        void Update(T entity);
        void Save();
    }
```

I could change the controllers signature but my ultimate goal is to test it with something like Moq.

Comment: What is your intention with the `IUser` and `ITravelRequest` interfaces? Do you really ever intend to have different user implementations for that `IUser` interface? Don't forget that interfaces are meant for abstracting behavior. There's no use in abstracting data. I believe that those two interfaces are useless. Remove those interfaces and your problems will be gone.

Comment: The main reason I have those is for testing. You are right they are probably useless. I have found a way around my problem but I would like to know If what I intended to do initially is even possible.

Comment: Your original IRepository interface must be invariant but cannot be either covariant or contravariant. Because in C#, if you want to make a type parameter T of an interface covariant, you have to specify the 'out' parameter modifier. With that modifier it means in your interface T can only be outputted. Add/Delete/Update violate these restriction. Same for contravariant, you have to specify 'in' modifier but after that you cannot have methods like Single/First/GetById. You can use only 'in' or 'out' but not both.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say `IRepository<T>` has an `Insert(T request)` method. `Repository<T>` implements this method as `Insert(T request)`, meaning that `Repository<TravelRequest>` has an `Insert(TravelRequest request)` method signature, *but it does not have an `Insert(ITravelRequest request)` signature.*

Comment: So how can I use the generics with interfaces. I need to test using moq.

Comment: @Daniel: Option 1: recognize that `TravelRequest` should be a POCO, without variable behavior, and therefore doesn't need to be mocked. Inject an `IRepository<TravelRequest>` and remove the `ITravelRequest` interface entirely. Option 2: Give `Repository<>` a second generic type to represent the type it should implement `IRepository<>` for. There are other options, but it all depends on your specific circumstance.

Answer (score 0):

To get rid of error, declare interface with `out` keyword.

```
public interface IRepository<out T> where T : IBaseEntity
{}
```

I was able to compile the following code successfully.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var travelRequestRepository = new Repository<TravelRequest>();
        var userRepository = new Repository<User>();
        test(travelRequestRepository,userRepository);
        Console.ReadLine();


    }

    static void test(IRepository<ITravelRequest> repository, IRepository<IUser> userRepositor)
    {

    }


    public interface IBaseEntity{}

    public interface IRepository<out T> where T : IBaseEntity
    {}

    public class Repository<T>:IRepository<T> where T:IBaseEntity
    {

    }

    public interface ITravelRequest : IBaseEntity
    {}

    public interface IUser : IBaseEntity
    {}

    public class TravelRequest : ITravelRequest
    {}

    public class User : IUser
    { }
```

Comment: The real `IRepository<T>` interface has methods (`Add\Delete\Update`) that cannot be used when `T` is covariant.